# In proportional editing is posible to move the sphere / circle of influence?

Tags: proportional-editing

What determines the position of the sphere of influence? It doesn't seems to follow my selection or the origin of my object.

It's possible to move it?

When you activate proportional editing and use the "G" key a white circle / sphere appears (the one that determines the reach of proportional editing). My questions are related to it. You can change their size with the scroll wheel, but it's possible to move it?

Comment: We would like to help, but this question is vague and unspecific. Could you please work on it to make it more understandable? 

Comment: Done, I made my question more specific.

Comment: Like, what do you mean? Usually you select a vertex and that becomes the 
"center of the circle". Do you want the center to be offset? Like do you want the selected vertex to no longer be the center of the circle?

Comment: Yes, something like just moving the circle freely, it's that possible?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no. the circle representing the influence of a proportional edit is always at the median of the vertices, edges, or faces selected before you activate the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible in blender 2.93 to change the position of the circle of influence in proportional editing. But I found a solution: Just extrude one of the faces in the direction you want the circle to move, that will make the center of the selection moves and the circle will move with it. After editing your model just delete the extra face.

Basically if you want the circle to move to the left extrude a face of your selection to the left, you can use the axis keys (<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd>) to extrude the face parallel to one axis, so the circle moves only in that axis. The more you want the circle to move to the left the more your extrude the extra face.

This is useful if you want the circle to be of certain size but at the same time you don't want it to affect one side of your model, then you move the circle with this method.

Answer (score 5):

While in *Edit Mode*, you can hide a portion of the model with <kbd>H</kbd>.  This will exclude the hidden portion from being affected by *Proportional Edit*.

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to restore hidden vertices.

[image]

Note that when multiple elements are selected, only one proportional edit circle will be displayed in the center of the selection, but the actual areas of influence are around each individual element.

[image]

Comment: I had my falloff set to constant for visual clarity.